# Why do the solids of revolution of $y=x$ about the OX and OY axes have different volumes?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

Given a line $y=f(x)$, the formulae for the solids of revolution are:
$$V_{OX} = \pi \int_{a}^{b} f(x)^{2} \mathrm{d} x$$
$$V_{OY} = 2\pi \int_{a}^{b} x f(x) \mathrm{d} x$$

Applying these formulae to $y=x$ yields:
$$V_{OX} = \pi \int_{a}^{b} x^2 \mathrm{d} x$$
$$V_{OY} = 2\pi \int_{a}^{b} x^2 \mathrm{d} x$$
Therefore, $V_{OY}=2 V_{OX}$, which does not make intuitive sense. Are these two solids fundamentally different or am I making some other kind of mistake?

Comment: Draw your solids in your example $x^2$ ... then it is quite clear that you are calculating the volume of two different objects: One is a subset of a  Paraboloid, the other of a Hyperboloid

Comment: That's right. Someone from my class posed the question and we all wrongly assumed both solids were cones. Now it's clear. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solids are different. The solid of revolution about the OX axis is a cone (or two, if $ab<0$) and the one about the OY axis is a cylinder *minus the cone(s)*. That's where the $V_{OY}=2 V_{OX}$ comes from: if you added both together, you would get the volume of the cylinder (which is 3 times that of the cone).

Here is the solid of revolution about the OX axis:
[image: Solid of revolution about OX]

And here is the solid of revolution about the OY axis:
[image: Solid of revolution about OY]

Answer (score 1):

$y=f(x), x=f(y) $ volume for the solids of revolution are:

$$V_{OX} = \pi \int_{0}^{a} f(x)^{2} d x$$
$$V_{OY} = \pi \int_{0}^{a} f(y) ^2 dy $$

For $ y=x , f(x)=f(y)  $ each case when rotated about respective axis the volume is $ = \pi a^3 /3 $ is same.